# Downloading a file in background and canceling

Tags: c#, download, background

I am trying to download a file in the background. With a small research i did i found this small class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35954/C-NET-Background-File-Downloader.
You will find the entire code in that link.

So my problem is that i can't delete the downloaded files until my form is closed.
How can i dispose the files so i can delete them?
I tried using `downloader.Stop();` however that was not the trick.
The handle is not disposed. I also tried `downloader.IsBusy = false;` which is the same but it didn't work neither.

I am pretty sure i am missing something simple here. Sorry for the troubles.

This is the exception thrown when trying to delete the file:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\path\download.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

A small reproducer of what i am doing.

```
downloader.LocalDirectory = mp3Path;
downloader.Files.Clear();
downloader.Files.Add(new FileDownloaderApp.FileDownloader.FileInfo(aLinks[Link]));
downloader.Start();
Thread.Sleep(500);
downloader.DeleteCompletedFilesAfterCancel = true;
downloader.Stop();
downloader.IsBusy = false;
Thread.Sleep(500);
File.Delete(mp3Path + "\\" + downloader.CurrentFile.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use Thread.Sleep(500), you estimate time of your download? Maybe when you stop, the download still not finish yet.

I saw the link, have an event: Completed, check event downloader.Completed

```
downloader.Completed += new EventHandler(downloader_Completed);
```

You should try to handler this event, check when file downloaded and do anything if you want, and the downloader have DeleteCompletedFilesAfterCancel property, this will make the downloader automaticly delete file when completed.

```
downloader.LocalDirectory = mp3Path;
downloader.DeleteCompletedFilesAfterCancel = true;
downloader.Completed += new EventHandler(downloader_Completed);
downloader.Files.Clear();
downloader.Files.Add(new FileDownloaderApp.FileDownloader.FileInfo(aLinks[Link]));
downloader.Start();
private void downloader_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Do something if you want
}
```

Comment: Yeah but what if the download is corrupted. It returns after some minutes. That is why i am checking the downloaded size after some seconds and if it is very low i am stopping the download and trying to delete the file. And that's where my problem occures. I can not stop the download and delete the file.